# How to use Vuetify for a Keycloak Login theme

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, keycloak, freemarker

I'm still quite new to web development, so there might be some very basic misunderstandings on my part.

### What I'm trying to do:

We use Keycloak to manage access to a web app. The app is Vue project using Vuetify. To achieve a unified look, I want to use Vuetify to design the Keycloak theme for the login as well.

Here is the screendesign:

[image]

### What I've done so far:

I created the folder `keycloak/themes/my-theme`, and added these files:

[image]

I took the two ftl files from the base theme, then I tried to rewrite the login with Vuetify classes.

To do so I inspected the code of the elements I want in the Vuetify docs and worked them into `login.ftl`. While this did work more or less for the Log In button, it seems to be completely wrong for the inputs.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

The misalignment is probably fixable with a lot of fine tuning, but one thing I don't know what to do about is that the text inputs don't get activated when I click into them.

I'm pretty sure that copying code from the developer tools is the wrong way to do this. Is there any way to actually design a Keycloak theme with Vuetify? Without basically copying the Vuetify code?

Here is the current `login.ftl`:

```
<#import "template.ftl" as layout>
<@layout.registrationLayout displayInfo=social.displayInfo displayWide=(realm.password && social.providers??); section>
    <#if section = "header">
        ${msg("loginWelcomeMessage")}
    <#elseif section = "form">
    <div id="kc-form" <#if realm.password && social.providers??>class="${properties.kcContentWrapperClass!}"</#if>>
    <div id="kc-form-wrapper" <#if realm.password && social.providers??>class="${properties.kcFormSocialAccountContentClass!} ${properties.kcFormSocialAccountClass!}"</#if>>
        <#if realm.password>
            <form id="kc-form-login" onsubmit="login.disabled = true; return true;" action="${url.loginAction}" method="post">
                <div class="${properties.kcFormGroupClass!}">

                    <div class="v-input rom__text--darkblue theme--light v-text-field v-text-field--is-booted v-text-field--enclosed v-text-field--outlined v-text-field--placeholder">
                        <div class="v-input__control">
                            <div class="v-input__slot">
                                <div class="v-input__prepend-inner">
                                    <div class="v-input__icon v-input__icon--prepend-inner"><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate fas fa-user-circle theme--light"></i></div>
                                </div>
                                <fieldset aria-hidden="true">
                                    <legend style="width: 188.25px;"><span>​</span></legend>
                                </fieldset>
                                <div class="v-text-field__slot">
                                    <label for="username" class="v-label v-label--active" style="left: -28px; right: auto; position: absolute;">
                                        ${msg("usernameOrEmail")}
                                    </label>
                                <#if usernameEditDisabled??>
                                    <input tabindex="1" id="username" placeholder="Ihr Nutzername" type="text" value="${(login.username!'')}" type="text" disabled>
                                <#else>
                                    <input tabindex="1" id="username" placeholder="Ihr Nutzername" type="text">
                                </#if>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="v-text-field__details">
                                <div class="v-messages theme--light">
                                    <div class="v-messages__wrapper"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="${properties.kcFormGroupClass!}">
                    <label for="password" class="${properties.kcLabelClass!}">${msg("password")}</label>
                    <input tabindex="2" id="password" class="${properties.kcInputClass!}" name="password" type="password" autocomplete="off" />
                </div>

                <div class="${properties.kcFormGroupClass!} ${properties.kcFormSettingClass!}">
                    <div id="kc-form-options">
                        <#if realm.rememberMe && !usernameEditDisabled??>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <#if login.rememberMe??>
                                        <input tabindex="3" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe" type="checkbox" checked> ${msg("rememberMe")}
                                    <#else>
                                        <input tabindex="3" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe" type="checkbox"> ${msg("rememberMe")}
                                    </#if>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </#if>
                        </div>
                        <div class="${properties.kcFormOptionsWrapperClass!}">
                            <#if realm.resetPasswordAllowed>
                                <span><a tabindex="5" href="${url.loginResetCredentialsUrl}">${msg("doForgotPassword")}</a></span>
                            </#if>
                        </div>

                </div>

                <div id="kc-form-buttons" class="${properties.kcFormGroupClass!} align-center justify-center">
                    <input type="hidden" id="id-hidden-input" name="credentialId" <#if auth.selectedCredential?has_content>value="${auth.selectedCredential}"</#if>/>
                    <button tabindex="4" name="login" id="kc-login" type="submit" class=" align-center justify-center v-btn rom__darkblue rom__text--white elevation-2 v-size--large">
                    <i class="v-icon v-icon--left fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>
                        ${msg("doLogIn")}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </#if>
        </div>
        <#if realm.password && social.providers??>
            <div id="kc-social-providers" class="${properties.kcFormSocialAccountContentClass!} ${properties.kcFormSocialAccountClass!}">
                <ul class="${properties.kcFormSocialAccountListClass!} <#if social.providers?size gt 4>${properties.kcFormSocialAccountDoubleListClass!}</#if>">
                    <#list social.providers as p>
                        <li class="${properties.kcFormSocialAccountListLinkClass!}"><a href="${p.loginUrl}" id="zocial-${p.alias}" class="zocial ${p.providerId}"> <span>${p.displayName}</span></a></li>
                    </#list>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </#if>
    </div>
    <#elseif section = "info" >
        <#if realm.password && realm.registrationAllowed && !registrationDisabled??>
            <div id="kc-registration">
                <span>${msg("noAccount")} <a tabindex="6" href="${url.registrationUrl}">${msg("doRegister")}</a></span>
            </div>
        </#if>
    </#if>

</@layout.registrationLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using Vuetify styles only. I would try to use Vue with the top element:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#kc-form",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(), 
...
```

And then I would create all inputs with Vuetify, e.g. username:

```
<v-text-field label="Username or email" id="username" />
```

But you need to mimic those original HTML inputs, so you need to add also some parameters, e.g. name - I would use mounted for that - naive implementation:

```
mounted() {
  document.getElementById("username").setAttribute("name", "username")
}
```

It may need also changes in the layout template and more tweaks to have naive Vuetify feel and full Keycloak functionality. It will be nice if you share your results (even incomplete) on the GitHub.

Proof of concept: https://github.com/jangaraj/vuetify-keycloak-theme/ :

[image]

Comment: How about adding vuetify to an vue project that uses webpack.config.js for creating .ftl files?